# How to get intent data when cancelled any StartActivityForResult

Tags: xamarin.android

If cancelled any StartActivityForResult manually then didn’t get data in ActivityResult, Is it possible to get data. If yes then elaborate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data if you call `SetResult()` method in the other Activity. You could try to put it in `OnBackPressed()` method.
For example:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {            
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.PutExtra("Text", "Test");
        SetResult(Result.Canceled, intent);
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: @ShashikantYadav Could you mark my reply as the answer?

Comment: Marked but my reputation is less then 15 so error occurred for not accepted once get more then 15 sure I will do